# Extjs panel above modal mask

Tags: extjs, modal-dialog

I need to display an info panel in my app, even if a modal window is open. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the modal panel is that is 'top of the pile' and nothing should be above it, so I would really examine what you are trying to achieve, whether you should be overlaying another element or whether the modal panel does need to be modal at all.

If you still want to push ahead, the best way to do it is to set the individual CSS z-index property of the panel you want above to a massive value so it is promoted above the modal layer (i.e. 999999999999), or to create a new modal window on top of the other modal window, and then add your content/panel into that.

If you wish to display a popup, perhaps an ExtJS messagebox is more appropriate than a panel?

Comment: Note the only reason a modal window is 'on top' of everything else is because by default it adopts a higher z-index than any other component, hence why you want to go higher than this.

Comment: ok, i'll try to explain though my english not so good. In my app take place some events. on every event i should popup modal window to process it. but i also should display the number of unprocessed events. This info have no attitude to this particular event but to all of them so i see no reason to display this info in "event processing window".